# Video of .mp4, .flv, .swf format not playing but downloads

Tags: video, download, playing

I am using a third party talking head service for a website. The below javascript does make the talking head to appear on home page of wordpress website.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress-flash/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/wthvideo/wthvideo.js"></script>
```

**Issue**:
1. Instead of playing the talking head downloads the video which is in .swf format.
2. Works in chrome but disappears once it's played rest of the browsers if we click on the play button it starts to download in a .mp4 format.

**Queries**:

1. What could be the issue causing a download instead of playing?
2. If it has to be dealt with MIME types of .swf or .flv or .mp4 then how to enable in a wamp localhost and on a live server as well?

The below is the library code being used to play the video which is to be included into the above javascript.

```
// JavaScript Document
if (typeof wthvideo == "undefined") {
    wthvideo = new Object();
}
wthvideo.params = {
    width:200,
    height:416,
    position:"fixed",
    doctype:"strict",
    left:"auto",
    right:"0px",
    top:"auto",
    bottom:"0px",
    centeroffset:"auto",
    color:0xCCCCCC,
    volume:70,
    autostart:"yes",
    fadein:0,
    fadeout:2,
    flip:"no",
    delay:0,
    delayclose:0,
    buffertime:3,
    controlbar:"mouse",
    exitbtn:"no",
    playbtn:"PlayVideo.png",
    playposition:"center",
    playtop:"bottom",
    exitoncomplete:"yes",
    oncepersession:"yes",
    vidlink:"no",
    openin:"_blank",
    path:"wthvideo",
    actorpic:"katiebankforeclosureschicago.png",
    flv:"katiebankforeclosureschicago.flv",
    h264:"katiebankforeclosureschicagoipad.mp4"};

var topPx = parseFloat(wthvideo.params.top);
var bottomPx = parseFloat(wthvideo.params.bottom);

wthvideo.hideDiv = function(){
    document.getElementById('wthvideo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
function onlyOnce() {
if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
var later = new Date();
later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;path=/;';
wthvideo.drawVideo();
}
}
function onlyOnce2() {
if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
var later = new Date();
later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;path=/;';
wthvideo.drawVideo();
}
}
var btnTop = (wthvideo.params.height)-(122);
var btnLeft = (wthvideo.params.width/2)-(51);
wthvideo.drawVideo= function(){
    var markUp = '';
    markUp += '<style type="text/css">';
    markUp += '#wthvideo {position:'+wthvideo.params.position+';width:'+wthvideo.params.width+'px;height:'+wthvideo.params.height+'px;margin-left:'+wthvideo.params.centeroffset+';left:'+wthvideo.params.left+';right:'+wthvideo.params.right+';top:'+wthvideo.params.top+';bottom:'+wthvideo.params.bottom+';z-index:99999;cursor: pointer;}';
    markUp +=  '#wthvideo img{opacity:\1;padding-top:'+btnTop+'px;;padding-left:'+btnLeft+'px;border-style: none;opacity:1;}'; 
    markUp +=  '#wthvideo img:hover{opacity:0.9;}'; 
    markUp +=  '#wthvideo div{background-image:url("'+wthvideo.params.path+'/'+wthvideo.params.actorpic+'")';
    markUp += '</style>';
    markUp += '<div id="wthvideo">';
    markUp += '  <object id="objvideo" style="outline:none;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="'+wthvideo.params.width+'" height="'+wthvideo.params.height+'" data="'+wthvideo.params.path+'/wthplayer.swf">';
    markUp += '    <param name="movie" value="'+wthvideo.params.path+'/wthplayer.swf" />';
    markUp += '    <param name="quality" value="high" />';
    markUp += '    <param name="flashvars" value="vurl='+wthvideo.params.flv+'&amp;vwidth='+wthvideo.params.width+'&amp;vheight='+wthvideo.params.height+'&amp;actorpic='+wthvideo.params.path+'/'+wthvideo.params.actorpic+'&amp;autostart='+wthvideo.params.autostart+'&amp;exitoncomplete='+wthvideo.params.exitoncomplete+'&amp;vbuff='+wthvideo.params.buffertime+'&amp;vdelay='+wthvideo.params.delay+'&amp;vcolor='+wthvideo.params.color+'&amp;vlink='+wthvideo.params.vidlink+'&amp;openin='+wthvideo.params.openin+'&amp;delayclose='+wthvideo.params.delayclose+'&amp;fadein='+wthvideo.params.fadein+'&amp;fadeout='+wthvideo.params.fadeout+'&amp;vvol='+wthvideo.params.volume+'&amp;playbtn='+wthvideo.params.path+'/'+wthvideo.params.playbtn+'&amp;playpos='+wthvideo.params.playposition+'&amp;playtop='+wthvideo.params.playtop+'&amp;hflip='+wthvideo.params.flip+'&amp;controlbar='+wthvideo.params.controlbar+'&amp;exitbtn='+wthvideo.params.exitbtn+'" />';
    markUp += '    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />';
    markUp += '    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />';
    markUp += '    <param name="swfversion" value="9.0.45.0" />';
    markUp +=  '    <div>';
    markUp +=  '<a href="'+wthvideo.params.path+'/'+wthvideo.params.h264+'"><img src="'+wthvideo.params.path+'/'+wthvideo.params.playbtn+'" alt="Click to Play" width="103" height="122" /></a>';
    markUp +=  '       </div>';
    markUp += '  </object>';
    markUp += '</div>';
    if (wthvideo.params.position == "fixed") {
        if (wthvideo.params.doctype == "quirks") {
            if (wthvideo.params.top == "auto") {
                        markUp += '<!--[if IE]>';
                        markUp += '<style type="text/css">';
                        markUp += '#wthvideo {position:absolute; top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop - 1 + (offsetParent.clientHeight-this.clientHeight) + '+bottomPx+' + "px")}';
                        markUp += '</style>';
                        markUp += '<![endif]-->';}
                    else {
                            markUp += '<!--[if IE]>';
                            markUp += '<style type="text/css">';
                            markUp += '#wthvideo {position: absolute !important;top: expression(((document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + (!this.offsetHeight && 0)) + '+topPx+' + "px")';
                            markUp += '</style>';
                            markUp += '<![endif]-->';}
                    }
                else {
                        markUp += '<!--[if lte IE 6]>';
                        markUp += '<style type="text/css">';
                        markUp += 'html, body{height: 100%;overflow: auto;}#wthvideo {position: absolute;}';
                        markUp += '</style>';
                        markUp += '<![endif]-->';
            }
        }


document.write(markUp);


}
function hideDiv() {
    wthvideo.hideDiv();
}

if (wthvideo.params.autostart=="oncethenpic") {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
        var later = new Date();
        later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
        document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;path=/;';
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "yes";
        }
    else {
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "no";

    }
}

if (wthvideo.params.autostart=="oncethenmute") {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
        var later = new Date();
        later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
        document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;path=/;';
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "yes";
        }
    else {
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "mute";
    }
}

if (wthvideo.params.autostart=="onceonly") {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
        var later = new Date();
        later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
        document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;expires='+later.toGMTString();
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "yes";
        }
    else {
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "mute";
    }
}

if (wthvideo.params.autostart=="onceonlythenmute") {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
        var later = new Date();
        later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
        document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;expires='+later.toGMTString();
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "yes";
        }
    else {
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "mute";
    }
}
if (wthvideo.params.autostart=="onceonlythenpic") {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("hasSeen=true") == -1) {
        var later = new Date();
        later.setFullYear(later.getFullYear()+10);
        document.cookie = 'hasSeen=true;expires='+later.toGMTString();
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "yes";
        }
    else {
        wthvideo.params.autostart = "no";

    }
}

if (wthvideo.params.oncepersession == "yes") {
    onlyOnce();}
    else {
        if (wthvideo.params.oncepersession == "onceonly") {
            onlyOnce2();}
        else {
        wthvideo.drawVideo();
    }
    }


function thisMovie(movieName) {
         if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
             return window[movieName];
         } else {
             return document[movieName];
         }
     }

function exitWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').exitVideoWTH();
}
function pauseWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').pauseVideoWTH();
}

function unpauseWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').unpauseVideoWTH();
}
function playWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').playVideoWTH();
}
function stopWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').stopVideoWTH();
}
function muteWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').muteVolWTH();
}
function unmuteWTH() {
    thisMovie('objvideo').startVolWTH();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .flv, .mp4 and .swf either not found or simply downloads instead of playing the video, then check whether your browser has adobe flash player being installed or not. If it's installed it should play the website talking head.